# Bundles don't automatically create their .yaml files

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, composer-php

I've been trying to create and setup a project under Symfony 4.4 for a few hours now but it seems like i'm getting a problem when i'm downloading bundles or installing things (For example, Doctrine or FOSrest).

Multiple times in tutorials I've seen that all the people seemed to have files such as "Doctrine.yaml" which are supposed to be stored in config/packages. And it seems like these configuration files are automatically created upon downloading the files associated to it.

But in my case there's simply... nothing, I have to create manually all the files, and i'm not sure if that's normal and if not, how can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: For doctrine you need to use "composer require orm-pack" to get doctrine.yaml.  Not all bundles have the ability to create their config files.  Not sure if the FOS bundles do or not.  Nothing wrong with making one if you need it.  Off-topic but unless you need to deal with legacy code then take a look at the Symfony based [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/) for rest.  Much better than the more or less obsolete FOS code.

Comment: Please share more details. How **exactly** do you install the packages? Have you also installed `symfony/flex`?

Answer (score 0):

> And it seems like these configuration files are automatically created upon downloading the files associated to it.

You're looking for the ***Symfony*** *[recipes](https://github.com/symfony/recipes)* which allow composer packages via [Symfony/flex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html) to automate common tasks when you install a new bundle.

A more detailed explanation regarding how does flex work you'll find in the official documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/flex.html) when it was first introduced in Symfony 3.4, but note that is not maintained anymore for this version.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it. I simply was being too dumb. When I created the git repository, I did the installation wrong and I didn't immediatly notice that I was downloading things into the wrong repository.

Thanks for all the answers!